Help identifying power connector for LSI6160 SAS Switch
I just bought a couple of LSI SAS6160 switches off eBay, however neither of them have power adapters.  Newegg identifies the power supply with part number LSI00271 just in case that helps.
I've taken the cover off the switch and can see the power connector is a Foxconn, and is marked with A025A.
Here's a side view showing the markings on the connector:

and a couple of further close-ups:





Even though it's a terrible indicator of size, I included this one just to get a general sense of scale.  The individual markings are sixteenths of an inch, because North America:

Interestingly, it looks like there is possibly an alternate power connector, which I've connected a 12-volt power supply cable to, here:

I am, perhaps understandably, a little reticent to just plug that in to a PC power supply.  I imagine it is there for either factory testing or for integration into a different style cabinet.  For future visitors, the connector I show in the above image fits, but is not wired correctly to supply power as the image shows - do not connect power like that.  See the accepted answer for the male connector part number.

This is a 3-circuit coax power barrel connector.
CUI devices (now renamed "Same Sky") makes the jack and its mating plug. You can buy them from DigiKey.

Female jack: PJ-096H
Alternate Female jack: PJ-097H
Male plug: PP-065574-M


"3-circuits refers to the power connector being able to provide power to up to three electrically isolated circuits?" - Yes: Positive (inner cylinder), negative (outer cylinder), plus a control line (center pin).

I'm happy to report the PP-065574-M do indeed fit (I verified via a multimeter that the inner, outer, and control pins do make a connection to the PCB via a simple multimeter test).

looks very similar:
https://www.foxconn-connector.com/power_connector/JPD1135_M048_4F_3032.html
Manufacturer Part Number : JPD1135-M048-4F
Manufacturer : FOXCONN FIT
This looks like the authoritative site for that part number.

+1 The datasheet mentions for this product that the diameter of the out-most circle is 7.5mm, or about 0.3in., which matches OP's picture. Datasheet can be found here. The footprint also matches.
